# Viber doesn't start under X11

Tags: xorg, viber

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.
Viber application doesn't start under X11 - neither Appimage nor .deb version nor even Flatpak version. Does anybody experience the same issue?
At the same time Viber works under Wayland.

> OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
>
> Host: Inspiron 5584
>
> Kernel: 5.17.15-76051715-generic
>
> Resolution: 1920x1080
>
> DE: GNOME 42.4
>
> CPU: Intel i7-8565U (8) @ 4.600GHz
>
> GPU: Intel WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]
>
> GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX130
>
> Memory: 5072MiB / 15875MiB

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287450/viber-executable-crashes-on-ubuntu-20-10-21-04

Comment: @FedKad Unfortunately, doesn't. Tried all variants. So, I will keep switching between X11 and Wayland, cause some apps work on first one while others work on second one)
Thanks!

Comment: I am using Viber on Ubuntu 22.04 X11 Gnome. Sometimes Viber does not start on the first run. Try several times until it starts

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in KDE Plasma. I can't belive but what fixed my issue (and I tried it several times to see if it really matters) is changing my first keyboard layout to a language different from "English (US)" or "English (UK)". I've tried several English keyboard layouts and in some cases it worked but in my case I put "Bulgarian" as my fist layout (I'm form Bulgaria) and the moment I apply my settings this way e works. When I put back English on the top I can't start Viber (btw I use the flatpak version, but I've found some information that this might work wit .deb version too). I hope this might help!

Comment: Suprisingly it is true! I confirm it also works with Serbian keyboard (latin and cyrillic) as well as German. After starting it, you can switch to english and it still works. I am using KDE Plasma and X11 on Ubuntu 23.04. When I login in Wayland it work regardless of keyboard setting.

Comment: In my case i have had swiss and serbian,when i removed serbian now it works,i tried before that everything,so,its keyboard issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried `viber.deb`, [viber-unofficial from snap](https://snapcraft.io/viber-unofficial), but nothing worked. So I installed [Viber from Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/com.viber.Viber) by following these steps:

1. Install `flatpak`:

   ```
   sudo apt install flatpak
   ```
2. Add the Flathub repository:

   ```
   flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
   ```
3. Restart your session.
4. Install Viber:

   ```
   sudo flatpak install flathub com.viber.Viber
   ```
5. Now you can either run Viber from your system's launcher, or by running this command in a terminal:

   ```
   flatpak run com.viber.Viber
   ```

Comment: While my first suggestion would also be for the OP to try either the Snap or the Flatpak version of Viber (I prefer Flatpaks), they have stated that the Flatpak version hasn't worked for them.